# Redirect error in Org Babel's src to the results

Tags: shell, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

Org's babel could export the stdtout to results

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
echo "testing "
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: testing
```

and report error to a new buffer or mini-buffer

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
e 
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

the error appear in a new buffer

```
/bin/bash: line 1: e: command not found
```

How could redirect the error to a `#+RESULTS`?